# Symfony 2.1 Doctrine filters (enable/disable)

Tags: symfony, configuration, filter, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I'm currently implementing Doctrine [filters](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/filters.html) in my Symfony2.1 project with the following setup:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\Bundle\Entity;

class Article {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $status;
    ...
}

//app/config/config.yml
doctrine:
    orm:
        filters:
            status:
                class:   Acme\Bundle\Filter\StatusFilter
                enabled: false
        ....

//src/Acme/Bundle/Filter/StatusFilter.php
namespace Acme\Bundle\Filter;

use Acme\Bundle\Entity\Status;

class StatusFilter extends SQLFilter {

    public function addFilterConstraint(ClassMetadata $target, $alias)
    {
        $filter =
            $target->reflClass->implementsInterface('Acme\Bundle\Entity\Status')?
                $alias . '.status = ' . Status::PUBLISHED : '';

        return $filter;
    }
}
```

Where Acme\Bundle\Entity\Status is just an interface.
The code is working as expected when the filter is enabled in `config.yml`.

The problem is that I cannot retrieve all articles for administration!
Is there a way to enable this filter for a certain bundle?
p.s. I know how to enable and disable the filter with the EntityManager,
I just cannot find the proper place to do it for the frontend Bundle.

my admin section is accessible by route prefix `myadmin`

www.example.com/myadmin/ -> admin section = disable filter (disabled by default in config)
www.example.com/...      -> anything else = enable filter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there is no notion of bundle at Doctrine level. The only way I see would be to detect which controller is used, by parsing its className (reflection, ...) during a `kernel.request` event, or a `kernel.controller` event.

Then, if you detect that your controller is in `FrontendBundle`, just disable/enable your doctrine filter.

If you prefer using routing to detect when to disable/enable, just use `kernel.request` event. You will have access to all request parameters, via `$event->getRequest()->attributes->get('_controller')` for example.

Comment: Tnx Florian, already implemented and working fine! the link really helped a lot.

Comment: The link is broken (404). Can you please edit it?

Answer (score 14):

Looking at the Doctrine code, there are methods to enable and disable filters.

Once you have defined your filter in the config.yml file, you can enable/disable in a controller or service:

```
// 'status' is the unique name of the filter in the config file
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getFilters()->enable('status');

$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getFilters()->disable('status');
```

*Note: this was taken from Symfony 2.3. You would need to test this with previous versions of Symfony/Doctrine.*